# RecyclerView Not showing Text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to mobile development with kotlin and I am trying to add a new item to the recyclerview.

The item is added to the recycler view but the text is not visible. I don't get what it's wrong.
I am using Kotlin in Android Studio 4.2

The class AgentAttributes only contains two properties:val Name:String ,val Value:String

```
**activity_main.xml**
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="No emp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSearch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@android:string/search_go"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvAgentAttributes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSearch" />

**MainActivity.kt**

    private lateinit var agentAttributesAdapter:AgentAttributesAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //constructor
        agentAttributesAdapter =  AgentAttributesAdapter(mutableListOf())

        //Definition of Recycler view adapter
        binding.rvAgentAttributes.adapter = agentAttributesAdapter
        binding.rvAgentAttributes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        //THIS IS THE WAY THAT I AM TRYING TO ADD A NEW ITEM 
        val agentAttr = AgentAttributes("Nombre","JOEL ROMUALDO LOPEZ SALIDO")
        agentAttributesAdapter.addAttributes(agentAttr)



       

  

**AgentAttributesAdapter**


    class AgentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AgentViewHolder {
        return AgentViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.agent_details,
                parent,
                false
            )

        )
    

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AgentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(holder.itemView.context)
        binding = AgentDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        //val view = binding.root
        val currentAgent = agent_attributes[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            binding.tvAttribute.text = currentAgent.Name.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return agent_attributes.size
    }

    fun addAttributes(attr:AgentAttributes){
        agent_attributes.add(attr)
        notifyItemInserted(agent_attributes.size - 1)
    }
```

Comment: Please add your complete code so that we can help you better. A lot of your code is clipped.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to inflate your layout in the "binding" step:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ChoicesViewHolder, pos: Int) {
    AgentDetailsBinding.bind(viewHolder.itemView).apply {

        val currentAgent = agent_attributes[position]
        tvAttribute.text = currentAgent.Name.toString()
    }
}
```

---

PS: variables should be lower case, so `currentAgent` should have a `name`, no `Name`